# Lo Shu Magic Square - Keeps showing 'false' is not defined and then Invalid

Tags: python

I want my code to show that all rows, columns, and diagonals equal 15. And the numbers 1-9 can only show once in the 3 x 3 grid.

My code keeps telling me that false is not defined so when I change the false to "False" with a capital F all my code turns up as invalid instead of valid. The first 3 rows of my input file should show up as valid so I'm a bit confused.

input file:

```
4 3 8 9 5 1 2 7 6
8 3 4 1 5 9 6 7 2
6 1 8 7 5 3 2 9 4
6 9 8 7 5 3 2 1 4
6 1 8 7 5 3 2 1 4
6 1 3 2 9 4 8 7 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

my code:

```
def contains(grid, i):
#Returns true if i appears in the grid & returns false otherwise
    for row in grid:
        for value in row:
            if value == i:
                return true
    return False


def isValidMagicSquare(grid):
#make sure each # appears exactly once in grid
    for i in range(1, 10):
        if not contains(grid, i):
          return False
#make sure rows add to 15
    for row in grid:
        r1 = sum(grid[0])
        r2 = sum(grid[1])
        r3 = sum(grid[2])
        if r1 == 15 and r2 == 15 and r3 == 15:
            return true
        else:
            return false
#Make sure columns equal 15
    for column in grid:
        c1 = grid[0][0]+ grid[1][0]+ grid[2][0]
        c2 = grid[0][1]+ grid[1][1]+ grid[2][1]
        c3 = grid[0][2]+ grid[1][2]+ grid[2][2]
        if c1 == 15 and c2 == 15 and c3 == 15:
            return true
        else:
            return false
#Make sure diagonals equal 15
    for diagonal in grid:
        dL = full[0][0]+ full[1][1]+ full[2][2]
        dR = full[0][2]+ full[1][1]+ full[2][0]
        if dL == 15 and dR == 15:
            return true
        else:
            return false

def main():
    lst = []
    f = open('input.txt')
    for line in f:
        grid = [0, 0, 0]
        grid[0] = lst[0:3]
        grid[1] = lst[3:6]
        grid[2] = lst[6:9]
        if isValidMagicSquare(grid):
            print("Valid")
        else:
            print("Invalid")

main()
```

Its supposed to show:

```
valid
valid
valid
invalid
invalid
invalid
invalid
```

Comment: Your capitalization is wrong.  `false` is not the same as `False`, and the same for `true`.

Comment: Yeah I got that but even when I changed all the false and true to capital False and True it was still showing everything as invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():
    lst = []
    f = open('input.txt')
    for line in f:
        grid = [0, 0, 0]
        grid[0] = lst[0:3]
        grid[1] = lst[3:6]
        grid[2] = lst[6:9]
```

In this code, `lst` is always an empty list.  Therefore `lst[0:3]`, `lst[3:6]`, and `lst[6:9]` will also be empty lists.  Perhaps you meant `line[0:3]` instead?

However, even assuming that is what you meant, you still need to convert each input line to a list of integers.  Try this:

```
for line in f:
    numbers = [int(n) for n in line.split()]
    grid = [0, 0, 0]
    grid[0] = numbers[0:3]
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that comment! That helped but now my code output isn't showing the grid correctly?['4 3', ' 8 ', '9 5']
['8 3', ' 4 ', '1 5']
['6 1', ' 8 ', '7 5']
['6 9', ' 8 ', '7 5']
['6 1', ' 8 ', '7 5']
['6 1', ' 3 ', '2 9']
['5 5', ' 5 ', '5 5'] It looks like this now

Comment: Looks like you didn't do `[int(n) for n in line.split()]` as I suggested.

Comment: Thank you so much! I realized afterward that I forgot to split the lines and change them into number like you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues to work out...

1)  Here, you're comparing a number held as a string (in the grid) to a number held as an integer (passed in a i) - so this function will always return False.

```
def contains(grid, i):
#Returns true if i appears in the grid & returns false otherwise
    for row in grid:
        for value in row:
            if value == i:
                return true
    return False
```

Converting the integer to a string to compare will work:

```
def contains(grid, i):
#Returns true if i appears in the grid & returns false otherwise
    for row in grid:
        for value in row:
            if value == str(i):
                return true
    return False
```

2) *Then*, you'll run into the problem that this code throws an error, as you're trying to use the sum function on a string (e.g. '123') rather than a list of numbers (e.g. [1,2,3]) here:

```
r1 = sum(grid[0])
r2 = sum(grid[1])
r3 = sum(grid[2])
```

You can hack around this with a quick custom sum function:

```
def string_sum(s):
    return int(s[0]) + int(s[1]) + int(s[2])
```

...and then drop it in...

```
r1 = string_sum(grid[0])
r2 = string_sum(grid[1])
r3 = string_sum(grid[2])
```

At this point, it appears to work and (interestingly) give the answers you want, but there are still two problems, one major, one minor:

3) Your logic for the isValidMagicSquare function is broken overall: returning a value from a function ends the function's operation at that point.  Thus, as the row-checking section of logic *always* returns either true or false, you'll never move onto checking the columns or the diagonals - this code is never used.  For this, I think you will need a rethink of the logic and structure, which is probably beyond this scope of this question/answer.

4) You've got undeclared variables here:

```
dL = full[0][0]+ full[1][1]+ full[2][2]
dR = full[0][2]+ full[1][1]+ full[2][0]
```

I assume `full` should be `grid`.  But the code will run, as (as said) this section is never reached.